# Closure compiler, Backbone and meta programming

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, google-closure-compiler

I am trying to use Backbone.js and Closure Compiler in advanced mode. I wrote a convenient function that creates getters/setter for my `Backbone.Model`s using `Backbone.Model.defaults`, it looks like this:

```
some.defaultProperties = function(ctor) {
    if (!ctor.prototype.defaults)
        return;
    var defattr = function(name) {
        return {
            get: function() {
                return this.get(name);
            },
            set: function(val) {
                var diff = {};
                diff[name] = val;
                return this.set(diff);
            }
        };
    };
    var props = {};
    for (var attr in ctor.prototype.defaults) {
        if (ctor.prototype.defaults.hasOwnProperty(attr))
            props[attr] = defattr(attr);
    }
    Object.defineProperties(ctor.prototype, props);
};
```

Equivalent in CoffeeScript here http://srackham.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/getters-and-setters-for-backbone-model-attributes/

Now back to Closure Compiler in advanced mode. It doesn't seem to like it because I'm accessing those using normal property access syntax, ie. `model.color` instead of `model.get('color')`, that's the point. But Closure is mangling those, and therefore I get `undefined` instead of my value. Any workaround for this? (Except rewriting everything to use `get('attrname')`)?

**UPDATE** And of course, how would this work with `Backbone.Model.hasChanged` and other methods that take a string literal for attribute name.

Comment: I think you'll have to set the `language_in` parameter to `ECMASCRIPT5` to properly support getters & setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining your properties using quoted syntax:

```
props[attr]
```

But your problem is occurring when you try to access them via dotted syntax:

```
model.color
```

In ADVANCED_OPTIMAZATIONS, a cardinal rule is that you must reference a property consistently. See https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#propnames

It sounds like the easiest answer may be for you to use quoted syntax for these properties:

```
model['color']
```

However, you'll lose all renaming and dead code elimination for such properties.

Comment: Does that essentially mean that I have to abandon the techniques using dynamic nature of JS, and degrade my code to much poorer subset of it? Event though I'm not calling `defaultProperties` dynamically, but only at code loading time, where the code paths are traceable by the compiler?

Comment: No, but you must either a) make your property references consistent by using quoted syntax for such properties or b) use SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS which does not carry such a requirement.

Comment: You might want to read http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2011/01/property-by-any-other-name-part-1.html for the full details of why things work that way.

Answer (score 1):

Any properties you create dynamically are "external" in advanced mode and you have three choices: (1) use quoted access (as Chad suggests) or (2) create externs or (3) use Simple mode and give up property rename and global dead code removal.